# Resizing a window after adding views programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to come up with a way to display a window that contains at least one view (that contains two labels, and maybe a progress indicator) and can resize as more views are added.

So, when a method is called, an array is passed in and depending on the number of entries in that array, that many views are added to the window and the window automatically resizes to hold that number of views.

Also, I'm trying to avoid Interface Builder, but if you have suggestions that include it's use, I won't scoff. =]

Does that make sense? It's late and I admittedly may not be thinking correctly.